# Using Ubuntu Server to PXE install Operating Systems?

Tags: boot, pxe

I was wondering if Ubuntu Server could be used to have a library of various operating system images (say, Windows 7, 8 & Windows Server 2008/2012 and possibly Ubuntu itself) that could be installed to client machines over the network. Possibly by PXE, CD or USB booting to something that would access the said network/server/library.

I've done a little homework into things like TFTP and PXE booting, but I've never come across a specific "follow this tutorial" solution that would allow me to use the ubuntu server in my workshop to push operating systems onto machines connected via a switch.

The practical application for this would be having IT firms, depts or MSP's capable of using KVM & switch stations to do OS reloads in bulk without having to haul slower physical media around from station to station.

I suppose you might compare this to a multi-platform counterpart to WAIK?

Insight greatly appreciated friends :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is our build doc for creating this kind of server using 10.04 LTS.  For NIC compatibility, we have since installed it on 12.04; the process is similar (except the config commands are in `/usr/sbin` now), but we haven't updated the doc for 12.04.

I've had some trouble getting the server to stay active after a reboot, but running the following two commands seems to kickstart it:

```
sudo restart tftpd-hpa
sudo restart ics-dhcp-server
```

We haven't tried this on 14.04 LTS yet. We've used this primarily for XP and Windows 7 systems.

Build Document – Clonezilla Disk Image Server

### SETUP:

Hardware:  Any desktop or server class machine with at least two hard disks – one for the OS and one for the disk images

Software:  Ubuntu Linux, Desktop Edition 10.4 LTS x64 (Lucid Lynx, Long Term Support)

### CONFIGURATION:

1. Install Ubuntu with the default options.  If a previous OS was installed on the disk, select “Use entire disk” for Ubuntu.  Name the machine “clonezilla”.
2. In System → Preferences → Network Connections, set the IPV4 Address parameters (edit `Auto Eth0`):

   ```
   Method: Manual
   IP Address: 192.168.0.11
   Netmask:    255.255.255.0
   Gateway:    192.168.0.1
   DNS Server: 10.10.1.5
   ```
3. In System → Administration → Disk Utility, create `/home/partimag`, format the second disk, and mount it on `/home/partimag`.

   Open a terminal session and `sudo -s` to become root.  Edit `/etc/fstab`, duplicate the `/dev/sda1` line, change `sda1` to `sdb1`, and change the `/` mount point to `/home/partimag`.  Leave all other options the same.
4. Run Update Manager and install all updates.  Reboot.
5. Open a terminal session and `sudo -s` to become root.  Edit `/etc/apt/sources.list`.  Add the following line to the end of the file:

   ```
   deb http://drbl.sourceforge.net/drbl-core drbl stable
   ```
6. Run the following commands:

   ```
   apt-get update
   apt-get install drbl
   /opt/drbl/sbin/drblsrv -i  (accepting the default options)
   /opt/drbl/sbin/drblpush -i
   ```

   --

   ```
   Domain:     mossbeachhomes.com
   NIS/YP: penguinzilla (the default)
   Client prefix:  clonezilla (the default)
   Ethernet:   eth0 (the default; answer “y” when prompted)
   Don't collect client MAC addresses
   Initial IP: 100
   How many:   50
   1st Mode:   0 (full DRBL)
   2nd Mode:   0 (full Clonezilla)
   Images: /home/partimag
   Accept all other defaults
   /opt/drbl/sbin/dcs
   Select all clients
   Clonezilla-start
   Beginner mode
   Select-in-client
   Accept all other defaults
   ```